# Vlookup the attribute and then Transpose rows to column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation, rpa

I have the following dataframe...

idx |Group | Family      | Quantity
1   |Apple | Fuji        |  100
2   |Apple | Granny Smith| 20
3   |Apple | Gala        |100
4   |Apple | Honeycrisp  |88
5   |Apple | Brecheche   | 60
6   |Apple | McIntosh    |70
7   |Apple |   Gala      | 44

and another data frame which consists of auditing attributes for each fruits category

Group audit     Audit variations

Orange  |  Size

```
     | Color

     | Number_Of_Items
```

Apple    | Quality

```
     | Variations

     | Family

     | Defect
```

Pineapple | Size

```
       |Firmness

       |    Special_Feature

        | Family

           color
```

Watermelon    | Freshness

```
          | Heaviness

          | Family

          | Weight
```

And I want to the following result from the dataframe

idx |Group  |Family     | Quantity  |Quality | variations|  Family  |  Defect
1   |Apple  |  Fuji      |  100
2   |Apple  |  Granny Smith |20
3   |Apple   |  Gala       | 100
4   |Apple   |  Honeycrisp | 88
5   |Apple   |  Brecheche   |  60
6   |Apple   |  McIntosh   | 70
7   Apple     Gala        44

Right now, I am manually doing a lookup on the group category of the first data frame with the "group Audit " column on the second. Afterward doing a transpose on the audit variation based on the Group Type. Since I am new to Python, is there any way to automate this process? This would save a lot of time. Suggestions are welcomed.